# How to calculate bandwidth on Google compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bandwidth-measuring

So i'm new to Google Compute Engine, i purchased a fresh copy of WHM/cPanel and installed it on my newly created instance of Google Compute Engine.

the one thing that i didn't ask myself about was **Bandwidth**, so i went to their calculator page and added **1TB** egress bandwidth, and the calculator gave an estimated **110 USD per month!**.

Does anyone has any experience with this? is this real or i'm doing the calculation the wrong way?

If this is true, how can anyone host a VPS server (using WHM) and at least 10 customers (cPanel accounts), the cost would be enormous. This is ridiculous.

Can anyone please clarify about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calculating correctly. I remember the days when bandwidth was measured in 1 Mbit increments. A T1 (1.5 Mbits/sec was $3,000 per month). With Google, AWS, Azure, etc. you are paying for Enterprise class networking and bandwidth. There are cheaper solutions with other vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the Google Group [discussion Thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/Glt7VSwh9Ug/nJM3GwHvDwAJ).

Depending on the region used in your calculation, it seems correct. However, the amount provided by Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator are only an estimate purposes only.

The actual charge will depend on factors such as, the actual traffic used within the billing cycle as well as the egress traffic region.

Example: The charge of an Egress - Americas/EMEA of an estimated traffic of 1,000 GB will not be the same with an Egress - Australia.

For more details on Egress traffic charges, see the [General network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general) page for egress through internal IP addresses charges and [Internet egress rates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#internet_egress), [Traffic through external IP addresses page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#externaliptraffic).

Furthermore, you may also check the pricing by [Product SKU](https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD&filter=egress%20traffic) see how these charges can be calculated in a currency other than USD for different regions.

Therefore, an estimated egress charge of 110 USD/Monthly does not mean that you will be automatically charge that amount in addition to any other computing resources used, but an estimate should you used up this 1TB of egress traffic within the billing cycle.

Comment: If i contacted support for a discount regarding bandwidth prices, will they respond?

Comment: Google Cloud Support team will always respond when a case is created. However if the question is about product pricing; I would suggest speaking with the [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) to discuss your needs. You may also review the following documentation on [committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts).